# Unable to get property 'message' of undefined or null reference

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer-11, webcrypto-api

I am trying to use the webcrypto API for both IE 11 and chrome. I'm getting the error `Unable to get property 'message' of undefined or null reference` when using the IE implementation.

I am using the implementation shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn265046(v=vs.85).

```
export function verifySocketMessage(signature: string, convertedData: any, publicKey: string) {
    publicKey = publicKey.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").split("-----")[2];

    let crypto = window.crypto || (<any>window).msCrypto;

    // IE 11 implementation
    let importOp = crypto.subtle.importKey("spki",
        base64ToArrayBufferEx(publicKey),
        {
            name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
            hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
        },
        true, ["verify"]);

    return Promise.resolve(importOp).then((key) => {
        let keyRes;
        key.oncomplete = (e) => {
            keyRes = e.target.result;
            console.log("onComplete", keyRes);

            let verifyOp = crypto.subtle.verify("RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
                keyRes, base64ToArrayBufferEx("signature"), strToAB("convertedData"));

            console.log("verifyOp", verifyOp); // This contains the error

            return Promise.resolve(verifyOp).then(verified => {
                console.log("in verified", verified);
                verified.onerror = (err) => {
                    console.log("in verified err", err);
                };

                verified.oncomplete = (e) => {
                    console.log("verified complete", e);
                };
            });
        };
    });


    // Chrome implementation
    // return crypto.subtle.importKey("spki",
    //     base64ToArrayBufferEx(publicKey),
    //     {
    //         name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    //         hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
    //     },
    //     true, ["verify"]).then(key => {
    //         console.log("key", key)
    //         return crypto.subtle.verify({
    //             name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5"
    //         } as any, key, base64ToArrayBufferEx(signature),
    //             strToAB(convertedData)).then(verified => {
    //                 console.log("verified", verified)
    //                 return Promise.resolve(verified);
    //             }, (err) => {
    //                 console.log("up err", err);
    //             });
    //     });

}
```

The parameters work just perfect and verify the message in chrome but fail in IE 11. When I try to do the exact implementation including the generation and signing of the keys shown in the IE11 docs, it works fine.

Is there something different between how IE11 keys are generated and chrome keys are generated? The data and keys I am using are generated on a chrome browser.

Comment: The generic `<any>` is suspect here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn It's just because typescript doesn't recognize window.msCrypto. It's the same thing that the windows example is doing in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Then the question concerns typescript - not javascript. Tags edited.